# How to immediately early return when Iterator gives error Result in a loop?

Tags: rust, error-handling

I'm in progress of learning Rust and I'm trying to apply similar style I'm using with C++. With C++ I would be using RAII and exceptions and the closest I can get with Rust is RAII combined with early return with error Result. As such, when I write code such as

```
fn parse_meminfo() -> Result<Meminfo, io::Error> {
  // ...
  let file = File::open("/proc/meminfo")?;
  for line in io::BufReader::new(file).lines() {
    let line = line?;
    // ...
```

**Is it possible to somehow avoid the fragment `let line = line?;` of code?** I already tried

```
for line in io::BufReader::new(file).lines()?
```

and

```
for line? in io::BufReader::new(file).lines()
```

and

```
for Ok(line) in io::BufReader::new(file).lines()
```

and

```
for line in io::BufReader::new(file).lines().expect("failed to read line")
```

but `rustc` wasn't happy with any of those. First and fourth have the test in logically wrong position because `?` and `expect()` are testing the iterator instead of the item, if I've understood correctly. Second was syntax error, and the syntax `Ok(line)` is not happy to ignore the error because that doesn't mean early return. I would like to have early return with the error if the iterator in the loop gives an error and adding one extra line of code just for that seems silly and that test seems a bit detached from the actual loop. Can you suggest anything better? If the `let line = line?;` is indeed the idiomatic style, then I guess I would have to learn to love it.

Comment: In Rust every error handling is explicit (except some panics such as overflows), and that is generally considered a good thing. So I'd say that it is idiomatic and that you should try to love it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to somehow avoid the fragment let line = line?; of code?

Depending how you're using `line`, you could just tack on the `?` over there. `expr?` simply desugars to<sup>1</sup>

```rust
match expr {
    Ok(v) => v,
    Err(e) => return e.into()
}
```

So you can see how the second attempt would not work (the left hand side of the `for...in` is an [irrefutable pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-02-refutability.html), not an expression).

The error handling here is largely orthogonal to the iteration, and iteration doesn't (at this juncture, though it seems unlikely that'll be added) have first-class support for error signaling, so you have an `Iterator<Item=Result<...>>` and you handle the `Result` however you wish.

If you don't care for the error reporting you could always `.lines().map(|v| v.expect(...)` and that'll immediately panic at the first error, but I don't know that that's what you're looking for.

---

1: that's not quite true anymore because of the `Try` trait, but close enough still

Comment: In addition to the `map/expect` thing you can also use `.lines().flatten()` to ignore the failing lines.

Comment: @rodrigo indeed, but the OP's message seems to indicate they want to handle / return the error (not just ignore it) so after consideration I didn't think that was worth mentioning.

Comment: Great info! I think the `flatten()` is nice if the context allows silently ignoring errors and keep going. I think I'll go with `line?` in every position that I'd use it because it makes it explicit that the code may abort there. Do you know if `rustc` (/LLVM) is smart enough to avoid repeated testing in generated assembly if I have multiple locations where I use `line?` instead of having one extra line at the start?